# using flowOn to perform an operation in the background and collect in the main thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code. And I was thinking that `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` will perform the map in the BackgroudThread. But the collect will be using the Main thread as that is the thread the coroutineScope started from.

```
suspend fun main() {
    println("Start")

    println(Thread.currentThread().name)

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            flowOf(1, 2, 3)
                .map {
                    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
                    it * 2
                }
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect {
                        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
                        println("Number: $it")
                }
        }
    }
    println("End")
}
```

However, its printing the following, so the map and collect are in the backgroundThread:

```
Start
main
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Number: 2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Number: 4
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Number: 6
End
```

Answer (score 2):

> But the collect will be using the Main thread as that is the thread the coroutineScope started from.

This sentence contains the wrong assumption that `launch { }` uses the same dispatcher as the coroutine it's launched from. It actually uses the dispatcher from the current `coroutineContext`, and it may or may not be specified there. If not specified, it uses the `Default` dispatcher.

The latter is the case in your code. `suspend fun main()` is called with an empty coroutine context, so `launch { }` will use the `Default` dispatcher.

We can see this if we add more diagnostic printing to your code:

```
suspend fun main() {
    println("Start ${Thread.currentThread().name}, $coroutineContext")

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            println("launch ${Thread.currentThread().name}, $coroutineContext")
            flowOf(1, 2, 3)
                    .map {
                        println("map ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                        it * 2
                    }
                    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                    .collect {
                        println("Number: $it, thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    }
        }
    }
    println("End")
}
```

This prints

```
Start main, EmptyCoroutineContext
launch DefaultDispatcher-worker-1, [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@2f0a9fe4, Dispatchers.Default]
map DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
map DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
map DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Number: 2, thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Number: 4, thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Number: 6, thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

We can now see that the top-level coroutine context is empty, so the coroutine was launched in the `Default` dispatcher. As you expect, `collect` executes in that same dispatcher.

Now, there's also an explanation needed as to why you see the thread names all starting with `DefaultDispatcher`, even when using the `IO` dispatcher.

You can't distinguish between the `IO` and `Default` thread pools using the thread name, because these two are coupled together and threads move between them as needed. The implementation doesn't change the thread name every time it changes ownership.

Here's some code that proves this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

suspend fun main() {
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}
```

Example of output:

```
main
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

In your code, there's evidence that a thread different from the one carrying the launched coroutine was used for the `map` stage, so `DefaultDispatcher-worker-2` was most likely assigned to the IO dispatcher in that run.

Answer (score 1):

[flow collection](https://flow%20collect) always happens in the the context calling Coroutine which calls flow (not coroutineScope).
If you call flow from "threadnamed-z", you can change the thread(dispatcher or whatever kotlin calls it) of the concurrent code which runs the flow{} and map{} block by calling [flowOn( relevant_dispatcher)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flowon-operator), but you can only collect on "threadnamed-z" ([docs ref](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#a-common-pitfall-when-using-withcontext)).

by calling  coroutineScope {launch{}} you are effectively stating the code in launch block must run concurrently on some thread other than Main which in your case is named DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 which is also used to run  the collect block as well.

if you remove coroutineScope you will continue calling flow from main and will collect from main like below:

```
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {

println("Start")
//notice removal of coroutineScope

println(Thread.currentThread().name)
flowOf(1, 2, 3)
    .map {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        it * 2
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    .collect {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        println("Number: $it")

    }
println("End")
}
```